# ComponentWillMount warning

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-router-flux

I am creating a layout with  inside. I am getting to this scene from another. So at the beginning another layout is rendered. After i go to the second scene (with TextInput tag) i obtain warnings such as:

> componentWillMount is deprecated and will be removed in the next
>   major version. Use componentDidMount instead. As a temporary
>   workaround, you can rename to UNSAFE_componentWillMount. Please update
>   the following components: App, Container, Image, Text<
>   TouchableOpacity, Transitioner, View.

This is very strange, because I am not using componentWillMount method, so i guess that it is implicitly called.

This is the code of the component with

```
 class MainTopBarAfterSearch extends Component {
constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = { text: " " };
}

render() {
    const { topBarContainer, imageStyle, textInputStyle } = styles;
    return (
        <View style={topBarContainer}>
            <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => Actions.menu()}>
                <Image
                    source={require("../../../resources/menuWhite.png")}
                />
            </TouchableOpacity>
            <TextInput
                style={textInputStyle}
                placeholder="Begin to search"
                value={this.state.text}
                onChangeText={text => this.setState({ text })}
            />
            <Image source={require("../../../resources/filter.png")} />
        </View>
    );
}
}
```

Comment: Which version you are using of react?

Comment: "react": "^16.3.0-alpha.1",
    "react-native": "0.54.0",

Comment: [Here](https://medium.com/@baphemot/whats-new-in-react-16-3-d2c9b7b6193b) check this out

Answer (score 5):

Yes, because the `componentWillMount` and `componentWillReceiveProps` getting deprecated soon in React. I suggest you to use `componentDidMount` instead of `componentWillMount`.

But you will still get those yellow box warnings because `react-native` is still using those for the internal components like `Image`, `TouchableOpacity` and a lot of other components. We need to wait for a new update to get rid of those warnings. Don't worry, Happy coding.

Answer (score 0):

I think, the ref of `componentWillMount` is in `Component` class implementation. not in the extend.

Answer (score 0):

It is because **componentWillMount** will get deprecated soon in the next major version.Even if you are not using it getting this warning is to prevent you from using as it is the part of lifecycle we commonly use.

Answer (score 0):

ComponentWillMount is deprecated in react from version 16.  You should move all the code from the componentWillMount to the constructor or componentDidMount.

Please refer to below link for more explanation.
https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentwillmount

Comment: OP explicitly said they were not calling componentWillMount directly.

Answer (score 0):

**`componentWillMount`** could be easily fixed with a constructor initialization or possibly with **`componentDidMount`**

it work for me :)