# How to hide componentWillMount warnings

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm getting four big warnings that can not be minimized in my console. These warnings are from what I understand not because I have done anything wrong, but because react-router-dom and react-select use the deprecated componentWillMount function. How do I get rid of the warnings?

I have tried looking up the problem on this site, but the closest to a solution I have found is https://stackoverflow.com/a/49166225/12057512. Since the answer is from over a year ago I am wondering if this is still the case. Have these big/popular npm packages still not updated since then?

This is one of the warnings I get (the others are similar):

> react-dom.development.js:11494 Warning: componentWillMount has been
>   renamed, and is not recommended for use. See https:// fb .
>   me/react-async-component-lifecycle-hooks for details.
>
> - Move code with side effects to componentDidMount, and set initial state in the constructor.
> - Rename componentWillMount to UNSAFE_componentWillMount to suppress this warning in non-strict mode. In React 17.x, only the UNSAFE_ name
>     will work. To rename all deprecated lifecycles to their new names, you
>     can run `npx react-codemod rename-unsafe-lifecycles` in your project
>     source folder.
>
> Please update the following components: BrowserRouter, Route, Router,
>   Switch

(I actually tried to run "npx react-codemod rename-unsafe-lifecycles" but it made no difference)

I have no control over how these npm packages work internally, so I find it frustrating that I constantly get these warnings that I can not fix or remove.

Answer (score 7):

The best I found..

```js
const warn = console.warn;

function logWarning(...warnings){
  let showWarning = true;
  warnings.forEach(warning => {
    if (warning.includes("UNSAFE_")) showWarning = false;
    else if (warning.includes("SourceMap")) showWarning = false;
    else if (warning.includes("DevTools")) showWarning = false;
  });
  if(showWarning) warn(...warnings);
}


console.warn  = logWarning;
```

Comment: Hi @jeanmgirard. Isn't the colon after `...warnings` in the parameter list a typo? Or is it some syntax I'm not aware of?

Comment: @steinar Its Typescript. Should be `Array<['UNSAFE_' | 'SourceMap' | 'DevTools']>` probably

Answer (score 6):

The common way to fix this would be to update the affected libraries (as you say react-router and react-select). If these are being maintained, then they would release new versions that don't produce these warnings. If that is not an option for you, then I don't know, I don't think React has a way of suppressing specific warnings.

Note that the warnings are only shown in the dev build of React, they won't be shown in the production build of React (see [DOCs](https://reactjs.org/docs/optimizing-performance.html)).

Comment: Thank you so much! I had used "npm update" several times, but apparently react-router-dom had not been updated properly. This fixed the problem completely.

Comment: The latest released version of react-select apparently hasn't fixed this problem yet, but they have fixed it in an unreleased version. So I guess I'll just have to wait a few weeks and then the last part of this problem will be fixed. https://github.com/JedWatson/react-select/issues/3720

Comment: The question was "How to hide ... messages", not how to fix the reason. So it doesn't really answer the actual question and hence must not have been accepted.

Comment: @Onkeltem It solved the problem, so I assumed I was supposed to mark it as correct. But I suppose you are right, since the same problem may occur due to other reasons as well. I have unmarked it now.

Answer (score 1):

JeanMGirard's answer causes `Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded` in some instances like when you forget to add dependencies to the dependency array within the `useEffect` React Hook. This can make it very hard to debug certain bugs in your code.

Normally, React DevTools would handle this by displaying the warning cause and possible solutions.

Here's a solution which ensures React DevTools handles our warnings as normal, but hides the `UNSAFE_` warnings:

```
const backup = console.warn;

console.warn = function filterWarnings(warning) {
    // If the warning includes any of the following text, let's hide it.
    const supressedWarnings = [
        "Warning: componentWillMount has been renamed, and is not recommended for use.",
        "Warning: componentWillReceiveProps has been renamed, and is not recommended for use.",
        "Warning: componentWillUpdate has been renamed, and is not recommended for use.",
    ];

    if (warning.length && !supressedWarnings.some(entry => warning.includes(entry))) {
        backup.apply(console, arguments);
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Use code below:

```
console.disableYellowBox = true;
```

Comment: That does not seem to work.

Also, the reason why I want to get rid of those warnings is so that I can see the warnings that are relevant. Doesn't your code disable *all* warnings?

Comment: this is for react-native, not reactJS

Answer (score -2):

In index.android.js, you can use:

```
  console.disableYellowBox = true
  console.warn = () => {}
```